# how to hit http service deployed in cloud from postman?

Tags: rest, http, mule, cloud

I deployed my Http service in cloudhub.

```
<http:listener-config name="httpListenerConfig">
    <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8084" />
</http:listener-config>
```

I'm trying to hit the service as below
http://applicationName.cloudhub.io/api/emp?parm1=a&parm2=123

But i'm getting below error

[image]

Do i need to change anything in my uri or in cloud hub ?

Answer (score 2):

Cloudhub routes port 80 to 8081. So change port 8084 to 8081.

More info in the ports you can use. Here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-networking-guide

Comment: Even better, change it to ${http.port} (set automatically by Cloudhub). This way you can have a different value when running locally if something is already bound to 8081.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the properties `${http.port}` and `${https.port}` for the HTTP listener , when the application is deployed in CloudHub those properties are overrided with the values 8081 and 8082 respectively .

In the Cloudhub VPC the ports 8081 and 8082 are open by default in the firewall rules.

If you want to use a different port make sure to configure the firewall rules accordingly.

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

You can ping and see if applicationName.cloudhub.io is getting resolved?

Comment: Application is deployed in cloud, up and running